# Jquery - If parent has two or more children create ul else do not create ul

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I am trying to customize a plugin that renders the images of a Tumblr post with the following function.

So far I've only managed to add the class .photoset to the ul of a photo post, if there are 2 or more images.

```
function getImages(post) {
    //        console.log(post)
    var html = [];
    html.push("<ul class='tumblr_post_images'>")
    $.each(post.photos, function (i, photo) {
        html.push('<li class="photo"><img src=' + photo.alt_sizes[0].url + '></li>')            
    })

    $('.post_photo ul').has('li:nth-child(n+2)').addClass("photoset"); 

    html.push("</ul>")

    return html.join("");               
};
```

Ideally I would like it to render an ul only if there are more than 2 images in a post so that the markup is clean. I have tried some conditional statements but I just can't get this to work. Any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to T.J. Crowders' answer I managed to find the solution to my problem. Here's the code that works:

```
    //Function to retrieve all the images from the post. This builds an array which is then returned as html list of images.
       function getImages(post) {
var html = [];

// Get the HTML
if (post.photos.length === 1) {
    $.each(post.photos, function (i, photo) {
              html.push('<img src=' + photo.alt_sizes[0].url + '>')
                    })}
                else {
        // More than one
        html.push("<ul class='photoset'>")
        $.each(post.photos, function (i, photo) {
            html.push('<li class="photo"><img src=' + photo.alt_sizes[0].url + '></li>')            
        });
        html.push("</ul>");
    }
          return html.join("");
       }
```

**UPDATE 2**
There was a bug in T.J. Crowders' original answer. He fixed it and now his answer works!
Thanks!

Comment: +1 on the edit, Barmar.

Comment: Alexandros, it's very hard to tell what you actually want to do. Can you explain more thoroughly? And is there more than one place in your page where you may be doing this? Because it matters to the solution.

Comment: `<ul><li>content</li></ul>` doesn't dirty the markup much, and even so, it has O(1) (constant) dirtyness, regardless of number of items. Did you try `.children().length`?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder basically I want to create an ul only if there are 2 or more images in a photo post. This is the only place in my page where I will be doing this.

Comment: @Alexandros: Re your edit: It doesn't make any sense to use `$.each(post.photos` when you know that `post.photos` has only one entry. That's why I didn't do that in my answer. (I did just notice and fix a bug in my answer, though.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder weird I know but it works. Your original answer didn't work. However now after fixing the bug you found your solution works also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> basically I want to create an ul only if there are 2 or more images in a photo post

Then simply check `post.photos.length`:

```
function getImages(post) {
    var html = [];

    // Get the HTML
    if (post.photos.length) {
        // We have at least one image
        if (post.photos.length === 1) {
            // Just one image
            html.push('<img src=' + post.photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url + '>');
        }
        else {
            // More than one
            html.push("<ul class='tumblr_post_images'>")
            $.each(post.photos, function (i, photo) {
                html.push('<li class="photo"><img src=' + photo.alt_sizes[0].url + '></li>')            
            });
            html.push("</ul>");
        }
    }

    // Add or remove the class depending on whether we have more than one    
    $('.post_photo ul').toggleClass("photoset", post.photos.length > 1); 

    // Return the HTML (why are we returning it rather than putting it in the element here?)
    return html.join("");               
}
```

Also note I've added in the missing semicolons (*strongly* recommend not relying on the horror that is Automatic Semicolon Insertion) and removed the unnecessary one (function declarations are declarations, not expressions; there is no `;` at the end of them).

Comment: I marked your reply as the answer to this question, since Stackoverflow will not let me post an answer to my own question and you really helped me find the solution. However please see the update to my question with the code that worked.Cheers!

Comment: @Alexandros: *"...since Stackoverflow will not let me post an answer to my own question..."*  [Yes it will](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It's specifically allowed -- even encouraged -- to answer your own question. You can't *accept* the answer for two days, but you can after that. However, in this case, I think accepting my answer is appropriate; what you've posted to the question is fundamentally the same as the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `$('.post_photo ul').has('li:nth-child(n+2)').addClass("photoset");` with this code :

```
if (post.length == 2) {
    $('.post_photo ul').addClass("photoset")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this   `$(id).children().length` to get the count of child elements thanks